# Python/Django Not Appending Slash

Tags: python, regex, django

For some reason Django is not appending a slash at the end of variables that contain numeric characters:

test_A  --  works (goes to test_A/) 
test_1  --  does not (doesn't append the / at the end - giving me a 404)

I do have middleware installed and APPEND_SLASH = True.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

url.conf:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from dashboard import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^environment/(?P<environment_name_url>\w+)/$', views.environment, name='environment'),)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Environment(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

views.py:

```
def environment(request, environment_name_url):
    environment_name = environment_name_url.replace('_', ' ')
    context_dict = {'environment_name': environment_name}
    try:
        environment = Environment.objects.get(name=environment_name)
        pages = Page.objects.filter(environment=environment)
        context_dict['pages'] = pages
        context_dict['environment'] = environment
    except Environment.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    return render(request, 'dashboard/environment.html', context_dict)
```

Error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in dashboard_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    1. ^admin/
    2. ^dashboard/ ^$ [name='index']
    3. ^dashboard/ ^environment/(?P<environment_name_url>\w+)/$ [name='environment']
    4. media/(?P<path>.*)

The current URL, dashboard/environment/test_1, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: What are `test_1` and `test_A`? And what do you mean by "doesn't work"? What is your output?

Comment: They are environments... <environment_name_url>

Comment: test_A redirects properly to test_A/ ... test_1 doesn't append the trailing slash so I get a 404

Comment: Note that I have tried adding a ? to: 
url(r'^environment/(?P<environment_name_url>\w+)/?$'

but I still get the same result

Comment: The issue is not within the `url()` part. Adding a digit or alpha character does not change the behaviour of the given regex. I do see an error/incomplete code-part in your views.py snippet. You only start the try-except block, but the 'except' is missing. Could you add the missing code?

Comment: Thanks for adding the missing part. Too bad it did not solve the mystery yet. The code you've posted so far does not seem to contain the error. Could you post the debug info of the 404 page? This page has a text like `Using the URLconf defined in stackoverflow.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:` followed by a list of urls. I hope this list reveals the issue

Comment: Added above... thanks Wouter

Comment: This starts to get really interesting.. I've simulated your setup and experience no such problem. What specific version of Django are you using (x.x.x) and just to be sure: if you append a slash yourself the 404 is not shown?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80108/discussion-between-wouter-klein-heerenbrink-and-psh).

Comment: Okay I'm getting somewhere... after doing some more testing it only throws a 404 page **if the environment has a decimal point** in it... i.e. **test_4.2** does not work... **test_4** works.  Do I need to declare these variables as something besides a string maybe? btw.. sorry I should've tried this before posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extend your regular expressions. The problem is not that the slash is not appended, the problem is that none of the urls matches (with or without the slash).

Simple solution, to include the dot you should update your regular expression to also allow a dot:
`url(r'^environment/(?P<environment_name_url>[\w\.]-)/$', views.environment, name='environment'),)`

Your could improve it further to also allow a dash:
`url(r'^environment/(?P<environment_name_url>[\w\.-]+)/$', views.environment, name='environment'),)`

The latter would even allow /test-1.1_10/

Comment: That was it!! Works perfectly now! Thanks so much Wouter!!